# Switch div position for each odd container

Tags: jquery, html, css, switch-statement

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<div class="article">
 <div class="article_img"></div>
 <div class="article_preview"></div>
</div>
```

...and both **article_img** and **article_preview** have a declared width and height, **position relative** and **float:left;** so they align one next to another.

I know I can switch **article_img** with **article_preview** by using $`(".article_preview").before($("article_img"));` but how can I do this only for each odd .**article** ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/v2nkn1ej/3/

Comment: @mohitArora Thanks for the example, works nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
div.article:nth-child(even) div.article_img {
    float:right;
}
```

Of if you have to use jQuery

```
$('div.article:nth-child(even)').each(function() {
    $(".article_img", this).before($("article_preview", this));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I can do this with CSS but I was hoping for a jQuery method :)

Comment: You could use a css selector with jQuery to get every other article: `$('div.article:nth-child(even)').each(function() {});` then do what you need to with them inside that function

Comment: I tried the jquery version ( http://jsfiddle.net/v2nkn1ej/1/ ) and it's not working.

Comment: You had preview/image the wrong way around in your question... http://jsfiddle.net/v2nkn1ej/4/

Comment: The wrong way around? :-? I did say preview before image...what is wrong about that? Anyway, This works nice :) Thanks :) I will give it to you for fast response and the two ways of doing it ^^ Have a great day.

Comment: No problem - by the wrong way around I meant your example code which you implied was working - `$(".article_preview").before($("article_img"));`

Answer (score 1):

i know this is not perfect but will do the trick

```js
   $(".article:odd").each(function(i,e){
  
 $(this).children(".article_img").css("float","right");

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$('.article').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        var img = $(this).find('.article_img');
        $(this).find('.article_img').remove();
        $(this).find('.article_preview').before(img);
    }
});
```

For each article, check if it is odd, then clone the image in a var (so you can remove it), then remove it and put the copy before the preview.

EDIT:
Please use this code (after your comment):

```
$('.article').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).find('.article_preview').css('float', 'right');
        $(this).find('.article_img').css('float', 'right');
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it does work even if it's the other way around :D But +1 for you. Thanks :D